# What is the result after removing an element in the middle of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

When we remove an element from the middle of the `ArrayList` what's the result: will create a new list with old elements or elements which follow will be shifted to the left in old list?

Answer (score 2):

When you remove an element from an `ArrayList`, the indices of all the elements following the removed element are decreased by 1.

`ArrayList`s are backed by arrays. In the case of removal, the part of the backing array the follows the removed element is copied to the part of the array beginning at the index of the removed element. This is done via `System.arraycopy` :

```
public E remove(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);
    modCount++;
    E oldValue = elementData(index);
    int numMoved = size - index - 1;
    if (numMoved > 0)
        // this is the part that moves the following elements
        System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index, numMoved);
    elementData[--size] = null;
    return oldValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-int-):

> `public E remove(int index)`:
>   Removes the element at the specified position in this list. Shifts any
>   subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices).

Answer (score 1):

When you try  remove an element from `arrayList` method then remaining entries will shift back so there are no gaps.

Removes the element at the specified position in this list (optional operation). Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices). Returns the element that was removed from the list.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> will create a new list with old elements or elements which follow will be shifted to the left in old list

No, because `ArrayList` are mutables. When you remove an element, this affects the current `ArrayList` object reference, that will have one element less. The elements that were *after* the element that was removed will be shifted to the left.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Acc. to the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)), it shifts the elements to the left. Have a look

Answer (score 0):

> The elements after the one you are going to delete will be shifted to
>   the left. Array list elements will be rearranged.